# Where did the video go? It ran off with the voice memo

Tags: iphone, ios, messages, video-capture

The Messages app in iOS 8 provides a convenient function to record and send voice & video messages as part of an ongoing chat dialog.

**Receiving a call while using Messages' build-in recording functionality results in a total loss of the recording in progress.**

Assuming immediate access to any and all resources necessary, how can we go about recovering them?